# MS Access 2007 & SQL: SELECT ... IN ('get', 'list', 'of', 'variables', 'from', 'form'")

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In a form a user makes choices using checkboxes.

Then VBA commands collect these choices into a string with comma separated numbers:

```
Dim choices As String

If (Me!choice1) Then
    choices = "1,"
End If

If (Me!choice2) Then
    choices = choices & "2,"
End If
```

Then these choices are saved in an invisible text field:

`Me!choices.Value = choices` (e.g. "1, 2, 5")

Then a report is open and it's source is a query:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE MyTable.MyVariable In (Forms!MyForm!choices)`  doesn't work.

If I manually write "1, 2, 5" in the query instead of `Forms!MyPage!choices` then it works.

Have also tried changing the string to other formats `'1','2','5'` and `'1,2,5'`

The reference to the variable is correctly spelled. So, how do I send this string to such a query?

Comment: try `"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE MyTable.MyVariable In ("& Forms!MyForm!choices & ")"`

Comment: Paolo Falabella, thank you for the fast reply. Still no result. Interesting, though, when I changed the type of "MyVariable" from number to text, and manually tried searching for <code>WHERE MyTable.MyVariable In ('1','2','5')</code> - it worked. Do you have any more thoughts about it?

Comment: I haven't touched VBA or Access in a long time, but isn't there any way to see the generated SQL before launching it? How do you set the source for the report to `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE MyTable.MyVariable In (Forms!MyForm!choices)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you removed the last comma in `choices variable`? It seems, based on the code you provided, that you have `1,2,5,` instead of `1,2,5`

Try to change this line:

`Me!choices.Value = choices`

into this solution:

`Me!choices.Value = left(choices, len(choices)-1)`

Comment: Thank you KazJaw, you are right about the extra characters at the end. But, unfortunately, it didn't fix the main issue. I'll try to generate the report using VBA only, instead of the built-in Query tool.

Answer (score 0):

At the module level, `Dim` is equivalent to `Private`. As such, the expression `Forms!MyForm!choices` cannot see it. The 'quick fix' would be to change `Dim` to `Public`. However, a better solution would be to add a public accessor method. Further, there is no need to use an invisible text box - either just use a private string variable as the backing store, or don't cache the value at all. E.g.,

```
Option Explicit

Const MaxChoiceCount = 4 ' or whatever it actually is
Const ChoiceControlPrefix = "chkChoice" ' ditto

Private mChoices As String

Property Get Choices() As String
  Choices = mChoices
End Property

Private Sub UpdateChoices()
  Dim S As String, I As Integer
  For I = 1 To MaxChoiceCount
    If Me.Controls(ChoiceControlPrefix & I).Value Then S = S & I & ","
  Next I
  mChoices = Left$(S, Len(S) - 1)
End Sub
```

or

```
Option Explicit

Const MaxChoiceCount = 4 ' or whatever it actually is
Const ChoiceControlPrefix = "chkChoice" ' ditto

Function Choices() As String
  Dim S As String, I As Integer
  For I = 1 To MaxChoiceCount
    If Me.Controls(ChoiceControlPrefix & I).Value Then S = S & I & ","
  Next I
  Choices = Left$(S, Len(S) - 1)
End Property
```